# What is the origin of the following phrase?

Tags: phrase

A Chinese friend sent me a birthday card , on the card they wrote:

感谢你如此精彩耀眼，做我平淡岁月闪耀星辰

A quick Google and this phrase pops up where people are discussing the meaning , but I can't find an origin.

Is it from an ancient poem, a modern song, a book, something a celebrity said once, ... ?

Now it seems there are different ways to say it. For example 多谢 instead of 感谢, and another variation with 岁月里的星辰.

Anyway can anyone shed some light on the origin please ?

Also , I welcome simple translation/interpretations.

"Thank you for your brilliance, be my shining star throughout my ordinary days"

Comment: 做我平淡岁月闪耀星辰 appears to be ungrammatical, even though Chinese doen't have much of a grammar... minimally it needs a 的: 做我平淡岁月````的````闪耀星辰

Comment: The quality of Chinese lyric writers has been in decline for many decades. Can't expect much from them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is originally a song lyric, although at this point you might as well view it as its own quote-- which is why you will see variations and what not.  The song is  遠辰 by 陳粒。

As for a basic meaning, it is usually a love word. I am not going to pigeon hole your friend to say it *has* to be a confession though, as it could maybe be platonic or meme-ing etc-- just note it is common for the phrase to be used as a love confession. Regardless, the biggest point of the phrase is to address how special it is to meet someone important to you, and how they are shining among the sea of people in the world.

As for a basic translation, you could say something like "I am so grateful for you to shine so brightly, adding a dazzling light to my life over the years, just like the stars."

Common responses are addressing how love or fate drew you together to meet, although if it was a platonic vs romantic statement, you would want to make sure the reply sounded romantic or platonic in turn.  As a note on a birthday card and actual direct reply may not be needed the way you would respond in an actual face to face conversation.  Hope this helps (◐‿◑)

Comment: Thanks zagrycha , update: she is now my girlfriend :)

Comment: @Kantura congrats :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if X is meant as ex, as in ex-boyfriend or ex-girlfriend, but I think that's possible.

作词 : 丸丸萱
作曲 : 丸丸萱
编曲：Vento Cher 乐队

以下是一些杂乱的自白，大概只是说给一个人听的：
Below are some messy confessions, probably only meant for one person's ears:

感谢你如此精彩耀眼X，
Thank you for being a wonderful and dazzling X,
做我平淡岁月里的星辰
(and) for making my dull time sparkle like (bright) stars

“感谢你如此精彩耀眼X，做我平淡岁月里的星辰

你还没有察觉到自己的闪耀，
You haven't realised your own glamour,
就已经点亮了别人的故事
but already you illuminate other people's stories

美好的时光被回忆时过于滚烫，但不妨碍被铭记
我有幸得遇天空上最暖的那颗星，遇见最好的那个你
花光有生之年的所有运气，照耀漫漫长夜前途万里
你不相信离别后的重新相遇，就已经大步流星超前走去
可是你身后有一个人的身影依然在，依然在。”

I think the gist is: I miss you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if X is meant as ex, as in ex-boyfriend or ex-girlfriend, but I think that's possible.

作词 : 丸丸萱
作曲 : 丸丸萱
编曲：Vento Cher 乐队

以下是一些杂乱的自白，大概只是说给一个人听的：
Below are some messy confessions, probably only meant for one person's ears:

感谢你如此精彩耀眼X，
Thank you for being a wonderful and dazzling X,
做我平淡岁月里的星辰
(and) for making my dull time sparkle like (bright) stars

“感谢你如此精彩耀眼X，做我平淡岁月里的星辰

你还没有察觉到自己的闪耀，
You haven't realised your own glamour,
就已经点亮了别人的故事
but already you illuminate other people's stories

美好的时光被回忆时过于滚烫，但不妨碍被铭记
我有幸得遇天空上最暖的那颗星，遇见最好的那个你
花光有生之年的所有运气，照耀漫漫长夜前途万里
你不相信离别后的重新相遇，就已经大步流星超前走去
可是你身后有一个人的身影依然在，依然在。”

I think the gist is: I miss you.